# Can I have a computed property from an injected service?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an isAuthenticated property in a service that is currently injected on my application route, how can I have a computed property from the injected service in my route?

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    session : Ember.inject.service('market-session'),
    isUser : Ember.computed.oneWay('session.IsAuthenticated'),
}
```

Is this possible? In template doesn't seems to get the value.

Inside the template -

```
{{#if isUser}}
   User is authenticated
{{else}}
   User log in form
{{/if}}
```

This computed property only works if I move it to the controller, this should be working in both the route and controller right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: This seems to work, but if I try to do something in the template with this value, it seems to be always undefined/false.
Anyways, if I do this from the controller, it works in the template, but why is this behaviour, shouldn't this be working in both ways?

Comment: The template has no access to properties on the route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the service has been injected, you can access computed properties on the service exactly how you have it shown above.  From the Ember docs:

> Creates a property that lazily looks up a service in the container. There are no restrictions as to what objects a service can be injected into.

You can access both computed properties and call functions on the service object as you would expect.